# How to create a random permutation of an array?

Tags: c

I've written this function in C and I want it to create a random permutation or a list of numbers from 1 to n. I'm having trouble getting it to have no repeating numbers. So if you have n = 4, i would like it to return a random array containing 1-4 each only once, for example: {1,3,4,2}

```
int* random(int n) 
{
    int* r = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    // initial range of numbers
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        r[i]=i+1;
    }
    // shuffle
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
        int j = rand() % i;
        r[i] = r[j];
        r[j] = i;
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: lookup Fisher-Yates shuffle...

Answer (score 12):

Change your second `for` loop to:

```
for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; --i){
    //generate a random number [0, n-1]
    int j = rand() % (i+1);

    //swap the last element with element at random index
    int temp = r[i];
    r[i] = r[j];
    r[j] = temp;
}
```

This is a Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm. I have heard using `rand() % n` doesn't distribute uniformly, you've been warned.

And if you want to generate unique permutations everytime, you can store the generated permutations, maybe in a `Dictionary` or `Hashmap`, and then lookup everytime you return. I don't think `C` has a built in one but there should be libraries available.

Comment: In cases like the one in the question (and more generally wherever there's a known function which can generate the input sequence), a bit of time can be saved by not generating the original non-shuffled sequence at all, as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_.22inside-out.22_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most efficient way, but since you're already populating the array at the beginning, you could then just loop through the elements and for each one, pick a random index in the range of 1 to n, and swap with that item:

```
int* random(int n) 
{
    int* r = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        r[i]=i+1;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        int randIdx = rand() % n;
        // swap r[i] with r[randIdx]
        int t = r[i];
        r[i] = r[randIdx];
        r[randIdx] = t;
    }
  return r;
}
```

I don't know if this is the most efficient or even if it gives the best distribution.  But it's pretty simple :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat the above several times, and you don't want to get the same permutation every time, just add the following line at the beginning:

```c
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
```